# TextWriter not working because its being used by another process. Network 5.0

Tags: c#, system.io.file, system.io.directory

I am trying to create a console app on network version 5.0 using visual studio. The purpose is to read all the PNG files in a directory, and make a JSON file with the code:

```json
{
    "format_version": "1.16.100",
    "minecraft:texture_set": {
        "color": "*Filename*",
        "metalness_emissive_roughness": "*Filename_mer*"
    }
}
```

In it. And yes this is for Minecraft. The filename and the filename_mer are automatically filled in by code, but that isn't my issue.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Goto " + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + "\\Packages\\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\\LocalState\\games\\com.mojang\\resource_packs" + " And find the resource pack you want to generate files into");
        string pathname = Console.ReadLine();
        #region Message
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Looking for folder...");
        #endregion
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + "\\Packages\\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\\LocalState\\games\\com.mojang\\resource_packs\\" + pathname + "\\textures";
        #region Message
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Folder found in");
        Console.WriteLine(path);
        #endregion
        string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
        foreach (string paths in directories)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(paths);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                string filenameWithType = file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                string filename = filenameWithType.Substring(0, filenameWithType.LastIndexOf("."));
                string thisPath = file.Substring(0, file.LastIndexOf("\\"));
                if (filenameWithType.Substring(filenameWithType.LastIndexOf(".") + 1) == "png")
                {
                    string newPath = thisPath + "\\" + filename + ".texture_set.json";
                    File.Create(newPath);
                    List<string> codeInFile = new List<string>();
                    codeInFile.Clear();
                    codeInFile.Add("{");
                    codeInFile.Add("\"format_version\": \"1.16.100\",");
                    codeInFile.Add("\"minecraft:texture_set\": {");
                    codeInFile.Add("\"color\": \"" + filename + "\",");
                    codeInFile.Add("\"metalness_emissive_roughness\": \"" + filename + "_mer\"");
                    codeInFile.Add("}");
                    codeInFile.Add("}");
                    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(newPath, false);
                    foreach (string line in codeInFile)
                    {
                        tw.WriteLine(line);
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                    tw.Close();
                    string newPathtxt = thisPath + "\\" + filename + "_mer.png";
                    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(file);
                    using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height))
                    {
                        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
                        {
                            g.Clear(Color.Green);
                        }
                        b.Save(newPathtxt, ImageFormat.Png);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #region Message
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("All done, Your good to go!");
        #endregion
        Console.Read();
    }
```

This is all my code, on the file. It reads a directory which you enter, looks through the textures file, and for each PNG file in there it creates a JSON file with the code specified earlier. Although when run the code gives me this error.

```
    System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\https\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\resource_packs\Vanilla_Resource_Pack_1.17.10\textures\blocks\acacia_trapdoor.texture_set.json' because it is being used by another process.'
```

I cannot find any answers which fit my issue, I would appreciate any help.

This is a Minecraft Bedrock edition resource pack btw, not sure if that helps.

Comment: What is "network version 5.0"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this `File.Create(newPath);` or rethink your problem. It looks like a typo.

In short `File.Create(newPath)` is creating a `FileStream` and discarding it, leaving the file open and with a *share lock*. If you are trying to pre-create the file, at least use the `using` statement:

```
using (File.Create(newPath));
```

or `Close`

```
File.Create(newPath).Close();
```

or

```
File.WriteAllText(newPath, String.Empty);
```

or

```
File.WriteAllBytes(newPath, Array.Empty<byte>());
```

If you are just trying to create or overwrite the file `StreamWriter(newPath, false)` is good enough.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I didnt know File.Create made a filestream and that it had to be closed. I had never used File.create before and didnt know that was the issue since visual studio told me it was with the Textwriter not the file.create.

Again thank you so much! It works now.